# Update Mysql Column of JSON array via SQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I am storing a list of integers as JSON array inside the column called ConvertedIds inside a table SelectionLogs
The type of column is MediumText and some of the example values of the column are  [290766,319075,234525,325364,3472,34241,85643,11344556,88723,656378]

I am using following sql to generate the list of IDs from the column as rows

```
     SELECT hm.id FROM SelectionLogs hlog,
     JSON_TABLE(ConvertedIds, '$[*]' columns (Id int path '$')) AS hm
```

And then following query to extract further informations from other tables like

```
     SELECT hm.id,hc.firstname ,hc.lastname ,hc.email  FROM SelectionLogs hlog,
     JSON_TABLE(ConvertedIds, '$[*]' columns (Id int path '$')) AS hm        
     LEFT JOIN contacts hc ON hc.Id = hm.id
```

Now i have to update this column based on the presence of a given value of IDs
For example if an ID exists in this column on any rows , i have to update the array after removing the ID

For example: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] If ID : 3 exists , remove 3 and update column as [1,2,4,5,6,7]

I can use the following query to find the records from table SelectionLogs with given id present in column ConvertedIds

```
        SELECT DISTINCT hlog.Id FROM SelectionLogs hlog,
        JSON_TABLE(ConvertedIds, '$[*]' columns (Id int path '$')) AS hm        
        WHERE hm.id=427529
```

Now i have plans to iterate through each rows from my console program written in c#

```
             foreach row in result
              
               List<int> columnIds = read from column   ConvertedIds as list of int
               Remove the given int number from List 
               Update column ConvertedIds for given rowId  refreshed List
```

Can i perform the updation via SQL itself ?

Comment: For example: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] If ID : 3 exists , remove 3 and update column as [1,2,4,5,6,7] I am  trying to do this via an sql  statement itself basically . I am not sure the detailed explanation causes more confusions to reader

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6c8446a03a1f07e0339b1b713823f67b) with some explanations.

> ```
> -- source data
> CREATE TABLE t1 (id INT, val JSON) 
> SELECT 1 id, '[1,2,3]' val UNION SELECT 2, '[3,4,5]' UNION SELECT 3, '[5,6,7]';
>
> CREATE TABLE t2 (id INT) SELECT 1 id UNION SELECT 4;
> ```

> ```
> -- UPDATE source table
> UPDATE t1
> JOIN ( SELECT t1.id, JSON_ARRAYAGG(jsontable.id) val
>        FROM t1
>        CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(t1.val, 
>                             '$[*]' COLUMNS (id INT PATH '$')) jsontable
>        LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.id = jsontable.id
>        WHERE t2.id IS NULL
>        GROUP BY t1.id ) data_for_update USING (id)
> SET t1.val = data_for_update.val;
> ```